# Latex: obtain an empty row with central alignment

Tags: tables

I would like to have a table that looks like the image below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|} \hline 
            &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{A} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{B} \\ \cline{2-7} 
          1 & a & b & c & d & e & f \\ \hline
          2 & g & h & i & j & k & l \\ \hline 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

However, I cannot obtain the table with an entire empty row, like the **cold cache**, written in its center. Is there some way to do so?

[image]

I also want the caption below the table.

Comment: Can you extend you code to a compilable [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html)? Why isn't multicolumn not working for you?

Comment: @Johannes_B Multicolumn is working for me..but i am not able to obtain an entire empty row like "cold caches" and "warm caches" as are there in the figure. Thanks a lot for replying

Comment: `\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{cold caches}` does not work? btw: You should take a look at [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs). There are some information about typesetting tabular material nicely.

Comment: yes \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{cold caches} does not work me.

Comment: Then please, as requested before, prepare a minimal working example. See the link above to find instructions.

Comment: @Johannes_B Provided a minimal working example in the question

Comment: No, you did not. Please follow the link. A compilable example contains, a `\documentclass{}` and an `\end{document}`

Comment: @Johannes_B I hope now this is fine :)

Comment: @Rose your example is unrelated to the image you show, it has `A` spanning 3 columns you just want to span 8 instead. as in Kohannes' comment above.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Latex: obtain an empty row with central alignment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151262/latex-obtain-an-empty-row-with-central-alignment)

Answer (score 4):

In the following code, I've provided two ways of reproducing the table that you're after. The first table aims to produce things as you requested. You were on the right track with `\multicolumn`. Note that I've made the default cell alignment `r` rather than `l`, as it looks as if most of the cells are right-aligned in the image that you've posted. For those that are left-aligned (*i.e.*, those things in the first column), I've used a `\multicolumn{1}{l}{...}` command to change the alignment of these particular cells.

Finally, I would strongly recommend against creating a table like the way that you have requested. In particular, I would recommend reading the [`booktabs` documentation](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) (particularly section 2) for some recommendations about good typographical practices for typesetting tables.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs} % used for prettier tables
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} % needed to center caption

\begin{document}

Table~\ref{fig:replication-as-requested} replicates the image as you've requested, but Table~\ref{fig:replication-as-recommended} replicates the image as I would recommend, based on considerations from the \verb|booktabs| documentation.

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{LUBM 1 Billion (time in seconds)}\label{fig:replication-as-requested}
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
    \hline
    & Q1 & Q2 & Q3 & Q4 & Q5 & Q6 & Geom.~Mean \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{Cold caches} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{RDF-3X} & a & b & c & d & e & f & g  \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{MonetDB} & a & b & c & d & e & f & g \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{TripleBit} & a & b & c & d & e & f & g \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{Warm caches} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{RDF-3X} & a & b & c & d & e & f & g  \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{MonetDB} & a & b & c & d & e & f & g \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{TripleBit} & a & b & c & d & e & f & g \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{LUBM 1 Billion (time in seconds)}\label{fig:replication-as-recommended}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrr}
    \toprule
    & Q1 & Q2 & Q3 & Q4 & Q5 & Q6 & Geom.~Mean \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{8}{c}{Cold caches} \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{RDF-3X} & a & b & c & d & e & f & g  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{MonetDB} & a & b & c & d & e & f & g \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{TripleBit} & a & b & c & d & e & f & g \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{8}{c}{Warm caches} \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{RDF-3X} & a & b & c & d & e & f & g  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{MonetDB} & a & b & c & d & e & f & g \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{TripleBit} & a & b & c & d & e & f & g \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I extend your (not working example) to aan MWE in which I consider and add suggestion comments of Johannes_B. For design of table I agree with him. Possible MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}\centering
    \begin{tabular}{*{7}{|l}|} 
        \hline 
  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{A}
      &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{B}   \\
    \hline
1 & a & b & c & d & e & f       \\
    \hline 
    \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{cold cashes}   \\
    \hline
2 & g & h & i & j & k & l       \\ 
    \hline 
    \end{tabular}
\caption{My very important table}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I hope that above example will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Another attempt, close to the image you showed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[papersize={18cm,8cm}]{geometry} % change this line in actual case.
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}\centering
    \begin{tabular}{*{8}{|c}|} 
        \hline 
 & Q1 & Q2 & Q3 & Q4 & Q5 & Q6 & \multirow{2}{*}{Geom. Mean}\\ \cline{1-7}
 \#Results &10  &10&0&8&2528&4.39997&  \\    \hline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{Cold cashes}   \\    \hline
 RDF-3X &  &&&&&&  \\    \hline
 MonetDB &  &&&&&&  \\    \hline
 TripleBit &  &&&&&&  \\    \hline
    \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{Warm cashes}   \\    \hline
 RDF-3X &  &&&&&&  \\    \hline
 MonetDB &  &&&&&&  \\    \hline
 TripleBit & 0.0002 &0.0002&7.5977&0.0009&27.2772&36.5613& 0.0805 \\    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{LUBMI 1 Billion (time in seconds)}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```