# Latex: obtain an empty row with central alignment

Tags: tables, multicolumn

Is there a way to produce a table in LaTeX in the way as is depicted in the attached image?

[image]

I have tried the following code, but I am not able to obtain an entire empty row with, say, "cold cache" written in its center. Is there some way to do so in LaTeX?

```
\begin{tabular}{|l||l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{A}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{B}\\
        \cline{2-7}
        \hline\hline
        1 & a & b & c & d & e & f \\
        2 & g & h & i & j & k & l \\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
```

I mean, I want to get the right LaTeX code for the table in the image above, but with the exclusion of the "#Results" row.